# What am I doing wrong in this .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to set up clean URLs on my website using the Apache .htaccess file. The code below is allowing me to drop .php from any filename, and it redirects from example.com to www.example.com. But the first rule isn't working as I intend it to. It should treat example.com/s/$_GET['s'] as example.com/index?s=$_GET['s'] (like I mean to say that if you went to something like .example.com/s/blue-hat-5, you would get the same page you'd get going to example.com/index?s-blue-hat-5), but instead it is returning a 404 error. I know this is something dumb I've missed, but it's been killing me for days now. Any tips?

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^s/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /index.php?m=$1 [L,QSA]

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Comment: `It should treat http://www.example.com/s/$_GET['s']` --- it's not clear what you mean It's also not clear why you have multiple `Options`, `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase`

Comment: I mean to say that if you went to something like http://www.example.com/s/blue-hat-5, you would get the same page you'd get going to http://www.example.com/index?s-blue-hat-5

Comment: You haven't specified a rule that would perform such a rewrite. That's why you don't get the desired outcome.

Comment: Still, in your code there is no such a rule.

Comment: Doesn't the first RewriteRule? I ran it against htaccess.madewithlove.be and it checked out ok. Never set this up before, new to regular expressions. Is the isssue there?

Comment: Have you looked in your logs to see which exact file/url is 404ing? The rule `RewriteRule ^s/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /index.php?m=$1 [L,QSA]` should work. For example `http://www.example.com/s/ben` would change to `http://www.example.com/index.php?m=ben`

Comment: The first one does not have `s=` argument there. It has `m=`

Comment: The file is still showing me a 404 screen, but after altering the error doc lines from absolute URL to relative directory, the URL no longer redirects to my 404 page -- it instead appends a php to the URL and displays the contents of the 404. So going to example.com/m/ben loads examples.com/m/ben.php/ with a 404 screen. The message in my error log is this: ErrorDocument takes two arguments, ErrorDocument Apache configuration directive.

Comment: "The file is still showing me a 404" --- you haven't changed anything. Why should it magically start working?

Comment: Using the absolute paths was affecting the outcome in some way as the URL is now appending .php to the thing that should be $_GET['s']. If the problem isn't with my regular expression, what could it be?